# Not Redirect after submission the Django Forms

Tags: python, django

hi dear all of genious Django Expert . i am newbe in django . i having an issue for my form submission . my form is not redirect after click submit . 
my issue is below

```
<h1> this is views.py page <h1>

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from crud.models import Userlist
from crud.forms import UserListForm
# Create your views here.
def addforms(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect()
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = UserListForm()
    return render(request, 'crud/index.html', {'form': form})
def show(request):
    user9 = Userlist.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'crud/show.html', {'user': user9})
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'crud/index.html')
```

i adding my HTML forms file in there ...

```html
<form action="/crud/addforms/" class="post-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <br>
    <label>
        user Name :
            {{form.user_name}}
    </label>
        <br>
        <br>
    <label>
        user Email : {{form.user_email}}
    </label>
        <br>
        <br>
    <label>
        user phone :    {{form.user_phone_number}}
    </label>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now i adding the show user list HTML forms hear . this actual issue is that when i put user info to the submission form then it should be redirect show.html page . but this still stay after click the submit button ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>  
            <meta charset="UTF-8">  
            <title>Employee Records</title>  
        </head>
     <body>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">  
            <thead class="thead-dark">  
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>User Email</th>
                    <th>User Contact</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>  
                {% for dt in user9 %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ dt.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dt.user_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dt.user_email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ dt.user_phone_number }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/edit/{{ dt.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" >Edit</span></a>
                        <a href="/delete/{{ dt.id }}">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
            <br>
            <br>
        <center><a href="/crud/addforms" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Record</a></center>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That bare `try: except:` is hiding the error from you.

Comment: Have you tried: after form.save(), return redirect ('your_redirect_url_here')

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a path to redirect to, this post should help you out [redirect tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_page_redirection.htm) or [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect)

**EDIT:**

This is what I mean by path

```
def addform(request):
    response = redirect('/redirect-success/')
    return response
```

The problem is from here `return redirect()` you didn't specify where the form will redirect to. do something like this `return redirect('show')` `show` being the name of the path in your `urls.py`

Comment: thank you for your reply . but my urls is okay . i try to add urls with html forms to in this question but i can not add this showing some error form this site submission .

Comment: can you edit your question and add the error message or screenshot?

Comment: ohh sorry dear i try to edit my question in many time but showing an error after click the submission .